Taking sums of differential operators
If I define a differential operator:
T[i_] := D[#, x[i]] &

I am able to apply it multiple times to a function without any issues:
T[1]@T[2]@g[x[1], x[2]]

However, I am not able to apply a sum of differential operators to a function. I have tried both of the following:
(T[1] + T[2])@g[x[1], x[2]]
(T[1] + T[2])&@g[x[1], x[2]]


They both do not work but give different outputs.
It works fine if I define a single operator from the start:
O[i_,j_] := D[#, x[i]] + D[#, x[j]] &
O[i_,j_]@g[x[1], x[2]]

But I'd like to take sums and products of multiple different operators which would be tedious to write down as a single operator.
How can I apply a sum of differential operators to a function in Mathematica ?

try (T[1][#] + T[2][#])&@g[x[1], x[2]].

Try to define it as T[expr_, i_] := D[expr, x[i]] & and apply as (T[#, 1] + T[#, 2]) &[f[x[1, x[2]]]].
